# how to update if the checkbox is true or false

Tags: html, django

**template**

```
  {% for me in student %}
 <input type='checkbox' name="check[0]" value="1" {% if me.Asthma  %} checked="check"  {% endif %} /> Ashtma
 </td></tr><tr valign='top'><td>
<input type='checkbox' name="check[0]" value="1"  {% if me.CongenitalAnomalies  %}checked="check" {% endif %} /> Congenital Anomalies
 </td></tr><tr valign='top'><td>
<input type='checkbox' name="check[0]" value="1" {% if me.ContactLenses  %}checked="check" {% endif %}  /> Contact Lenses
 </td></tr><tr valign='top'><td>
 {% endfor %}
```

**views**

```
  asthma = request.POST.get('check[0]')
  congenitalAnomalies = request.POST.get('check[0]')
  Contact = request.POST.get('check[0]')
  update.Asthma=asthma
  update.CongenitalAnomalies=congenitalAnomalies
  update.ContactLenses = Contact
```

**models**

```
  Asthma=models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
  CongenitalAnomalies=models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True)
  ContactLenses=models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True)
```

it works fine if i do not check everything but I check one automatic-check all, please correct my code,

Comment: sorry your question is not clear are you getting some errors?if so please post the error traceback

Comment: you need to provide more details, like what is `update`? add more details for your views and model.

Comment: the error is when check one and click the update button the result is automatic-check all

Comment: But you've used the same name and value for each one. So obviously they will all do everything.

Comment: what should i do? can you give me an example?

Comment: Use different names, obviously. Why have you called everything `check[0]`? Call them what they are: `name="asthma"` etc.

Comment: do i change the value too?

Answer (score 0):

Use unique `name` attributes for your `<checkbox>` elements in your template:

```
{% for me in student %}
 <input type='checkbox' name="asthma" value="1" {% if me.Asthma  %} checked="check"  {% endif %} /> Ashtma
 </td></tr><tr valign='top'><td>
<input type='checkbox' name="congenital_anomalies" value="1"  {% if me.CongenitalAnomalies  %}checked="check" {% endif %} /> Congenital Anomalies
 </td></tr><tr valign='top'><td>
<input type='checkbox' name="contact-lenses" value="1" {% if me.ContactLenses  %}checked="check" {% endif %}  /> Contact Lenses
 </td></tr><tr valign='top'><td>
 {% endfor %}
```

You then also have to use the right names in your view:

```
asthma = request.POST.get('asthma')
congenitalAnomalies = request.POST.get('congenital_anomalies')
Contact = request.POST.get('contact-lenses')
update.Asthma=asthma
update.CongenitalAnomalies=congenitalAnomalies
update.ContactLenses = Contact
```

Note that this will only work if you update only one object in your view. If the code snippet from your view actually is in a loop, you will have to add the id of the object to the name.

```
<input type='checkbox' name="asthma-{me.id}" value="1" {% if me.Asthma  %} checked="check"  {% endif %}

for update in students:
    asthma = request.POST.get(f'asthma-{update.id}')
    ...
```

That being said, Django comes with very powerful [form handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/), which can make your life much easier.